# Link to Jquery Tab does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs, laravel-5

I am working on a L5 project and i am using a Jquery tab for one of its pages. I have a little menu for reaching tab contents without clicking just tabs.

```
<div id="aracislem" class="panel-collapse collapse">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://localhost/pages/aracislemler#aracaramatab">Araç Arama </a></li>
            <li><a href="http://localhost/pages/aracislemler#arackayittab">Araç Kayıt </a></li>
            <li><a href="http://localhost/pages/aracislemler#istatistiktab">İstatistik </a></li>
            <li><a href="http://localhost/pages/aracislemler#aractakiptab">Araç Takibi </a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any my tab is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#tab-container').tabs({
            active: $.cookie('activetab'),
            activate: function (event, ui) {
                $.cookie('activetab', ui.newTab.index(), {
                    expires: 10
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="tab-container" class='tab-container'>
    <ul>
        <li class='tab'><a href="#aracaramatab">Araç Arama</a></li>
        <li class='tab'><a href="#arackayittab">Araç Kayıt</a></li>
        <li class='tab'><a href="#istatistiktab">İstatistik</a></li>
        <li class='tab'><a href="#aractakiptab">Araç Takip</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class='panel-container'>
        <div id="aracaramatab">
            Araç Arama
        </div>
        <div id="arackayittab">
            Araç Kayıt
        </div>
        <div id="istatistiktab">
            İstatistik
        </div>
        <div id="aractakiptab">
            Araç Takip
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When i clik to menu links i cant reach to necessary tab, link changes in the browser but does not redirect to tab also when i click to tabs, content changes but links do not change. Anybody knows what am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Check this DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/mktgnp3e/1/

Your problem is when you click link and after going to link (it will redirect a different page?), want to active the tab, right?

So get the `url` first, then get the `hash`, then do the active tab step.

#### JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#tab-container").tabs({});
    
    // for testing purpose
    var url = "http://localhost/pages/aracislemler#arackayittab";
    
    // use this script for getting url
    //var url = window.location.href;
    var hash = url.substring(url.indexOf('#'));

    // trigger click to tab with url hash name
    $('#tab-container a[href='+hash+']').trigger('click');
});
```

*Use the line `var url = window.location.href;` for your app, then take out the current url getting test variable.

Comment: I ve tried it. It only works once when i click to a link after that if i click to any of these links from the menu, there is no redirection.